# grep: invalid content of \{\}

Tags: grep, regular-expression

Here's the command :

```
grep '\(2\)[[:digit:]]\{\1\}' numbers
```

What I want is to match exactly 2 digits after the digit '2', 3 digits if I change the digit '2' to '3' in my expression, 4 digits if ...

I'm using back-referencing here but when I execute this command I have the following output :

```
grep: invalid content of \{\}
```

How could one change my expression ?

**first solution :** 
*As serge answered :*

```
2[[:digit:]]\{1\}\|3[[:digit:]]\{2\}\|4[[:digit:]]\{3\}\|5[[:digit:]]\{4\}
```

That could actually work, but let's suppose I have `\(34\)` as the first sub-expression, I wish I could back-referencing that number so I don't have to implement the 34 cases (or more).

Comment: i think it should be `grep -E 'pattern'  inputfile`

Comment: @RahulPatil what is wrong to use Basic Regular Expressions ? for readability reason I could have used that right. But that doesn't help a lot since '{\1}' doesn't give any result still.

Comment: there are only 10 digits including '0'

Comment: @Oddant : Serge is logically correct, either there are only 10 possible cases or there is some token between the first "digit"(s) and the rest, or you are assuming something else about the context but using grep wrongly in your description.

Comment: @goldilocks please check my update

Answer (score 1):

Back-references are not allowed here. You have to write the expression that will describe all possible cases, e.g.:

```
2[[:digit:]]\{1\}\|3[[:digit:]]\{2\}\|4[[:digit:]]\{3\}\|5[[:digit:]]\{4\}
```

Comment: that could actually work, but please check my update to read why it is not really appropriate.

Comment: For completeness, `grep --line-regexp '1\|2[[:digit:]]\{1\}\|3[[:digit:]]\{2\}\|4[[:digit:]]\{3\}\|5[[:digit:]]\{4\}\|6[[:digit:]]\{5\}\|7[[:digit:]]\{6\}\|8[[:digit:]]\{7\}\|9[[:digit:]]\{8\}' numbers`

Comment: @Serge pease check my update

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you mean to hard-code the that first value instead of determining it from the actual first digit of the line. Consider something like this, then:

```
HOWMUCH=2 grep "\($HOWMUCH\)[[:digit:]]\{$HOWMUCH\}" numbers
```